# Migrating MySQL 8.0.33 to Aurora in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

In Amazon RDS, I am trying to migrate my MySQL 8.0.33 to Amazon Aurora.

I attempted to do this using both these methods:

- Creating a read replica
- Migrating a snapshot

The issue is that there doesn't seem to be a compatible Aurora version with MySQL 8.0.33. The latest Aurora version seems to be: Aurora MySQL 3.05.0 (Compatible with MySQL 8.0.32).

I then thought about downgrading the RDS instance to 8.0.32, but this does not seem to be an option. Only upgrading.

How can I handle this issue?

The only thing I can think of is exporting the data using MYSQL dump, and re-importing the data in a new Aurora instance.

Comment: Yes, you have to export data using mysql dump, and import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the recommended way is through `mysql` dump.  Alternatively, there is also [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) which could be considered as an alternative.